# React side-effect loop

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I was reading this [article](https://epicreact.dev/memoization-and-react/) to understand how React rendering mechanism. I came across this example:

```
function App() {
  const [body, setBody] = React.useState()
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState('idle')

  const fetchConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    body,
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  }
  const makeFetchRequest = () => (body ? fetch('/post', fetchConfig) : null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const promise = makeFetchRequest()

    // if no promise was returned, then we didn't make a request
    // so we'll exit early
    if (!promise) return

    setStatus('pending')

    promise.then(
      () => setStatus('fulfilled'),
      () => setStatus('rejected'),
    )
  }, [makeFetchRequest])

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // get form input values
    setBody(formInputValues)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* form inputs and other neat stuff... */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

The author stated that this `App` component will cause infinite rendering:

> Take a guess at what's going to happen. If you guessed "runaway
> side-effect loop" you're right! The reason is because React.useEffect
> will trigger a call to the given effect callback whenever individual
> elements of the dependency array changes. Our only dependency is
> makeFetchRequest and makeFetchRequest is created within the component
> and that means it's new every render.

I want to simulate this behavior with a simpler example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const fn = () => {
    setState(1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('side effect');
    fn();
  }, [fn]);
};

export default App;
```

I was expecting an infinite rendering because after the component re-renders, `fn` is called which causes `state` to change which causes a re-rendering, which causes a new instance of `fn` which should cause a re-rendering because we depend on it and this keeps going but this is not what's happening. The `useEffect` hook seems to only execute twice. But in the author's example it causes an infinite loop. I'm not sure what I'm understanding wrong here

**Updated**

I guess I understand it now.

*Author's case*

When the `useEffect` hook executes. It sets the `status` to pending and after the asynchronous operation the `status` is set again to either "fulfilled" or "rejected" so the `App` component is executed again with a new instance of `makeFetchRequest` causing the component to re-render, so on and so forth.

*My case*

The `useEffect` hook renders first time, calls `fn` and changes `state` which causes a re-render and a new instance of `fn` but here React recognized that the implementation remains unchanged so it doesn't re-render the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the function is declared outside of the component (i.e., a stable reference), React treats a function passed as a dependency to useEffect as a fresh reference on each render. This means that React analyzes function references to decide whether to re-execute the effect, even though fn is theoretically recreated on every render.

Since fn in your example is regenerated on each render, React recognizes it as a new reference. However, because the implementation of fn remains unchanged, React does not deem this to be a large enough change to cause the effect to occur again.

In the example provided in the article, `makeFetchRequest` is supplied straight into `useEffect's` dependency array. React treats it as a new reference and treats it as a change, thus even if it's recreated on every render, it still has the same effect.

You entered `fn` into the dependency array in your attempt. React treats `fn` as a new reference as well because it is recreated for each render. But in your example, since the logic inside the effect isn't greatly affected by `fn` being regenerated, React doesn't force the effect to happen on every render. React doesn't rerun the effect because it is intelligent enough to realize that even though fn is regenerated, its behavior doesn't change.

Therefore, React handles `dependencies differently` depending on whether they are stable references or not, which explains why the behavior you saw in your first try is different from what is described in the article. React interprets `makeFetchRequest` as a fresh reference on each render, which is why the effect in the article's example activates infinitely.

Comment: "makeFetchRequest is supplied directly as a dependency to useEffect, but it is rebuilt on each render". But why this isn't the case for `fn`? both functions seem to have a simple implementation and are supplied as dependencies to `useEffect`. I was expecting to have the same behavior

Comment: I updated my answer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added more info please check